# How to access 'this' tag instance inside tag lifecycle event?

Tags: riot.js

I'm trying to update an array every time my tag receives an update from parent tags. Here is my code:

```
var tag = function(opts){
  this.set = [];
  var self = this;

  this.on('updated', function(){
    var obj = opts.my_topics;
    var better_obj = {};
    for (var key in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var topic_title = key;
        better_obj = obj[key];
        better_obj['title'] = key;
      }
    }
    self.set.push(better_obj);
  })
}
```

Whenever I try to push(), I get an error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; database.js:60. The moment I remove the line of code for the push, the error disappears. Am I using this/self wrong in this case or could it be something else?

What I am trying to accomplish here is taking an object from opts (which receives regular updates), converting into an array, and using it for an `each` loop within my tag. I do not know how to do this other than a) what i'm trying to do now by accessing `this`, or b) rewiring my opts to deliver an array rather than an object (which is currently failing for me as I'm using Redux and it doesn't like dispatching non-objects).

Comment: Is that a tag file? the syntax doesn't look right to me. Why are you using var tag = function(opts){ ? if it's a tag file you don't need that

Comment: @vitomd It is a separate .js file for a tag. In my .html file I have: `<script>
    var search_results = require('./search_results/search_results.tag.js');
    search_results.call(this, this.opts);
  </script>`. This is a solution I found in order to separate the two. In any case, does this affect my ability to grab `this` inside a tag lifecycle event handler?

Comment: I don't know exactly how that works. I would try using the tag directly and see if it's work, because I'm not sure how Riot.js is compiling your tags in your sample.